# Making zsh brace expansion continue after a failed match

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have a simple cleanup script that runs:

```bash
rm *.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,....}
```

The problem is that it fails as soon as one of those file types doesn't exist in the folder.  e.g. if there are `png`'s, but no `jpg`'s, it just says `zsh: no matches found: *.jpg` and leaves all the `png`'s around.

Comment: The problem here isn't brace expansion, but filename generation. Brace expansion succeeds in producing multiple individual patterns, but all the patterns have to succeed before `rm` can run.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `bash` or shells in general, only `zsh`.

Comment: (In particular, with default settings in `bash`, a failure to find any `jpg` files would simply pass `*.jpg` as a literal argument to `bash`; `rm` would fail to delete a file named `*.jpg`, but would still be able to delete any other files it received as arguments.)

Comment: `bash` doesn't have glob qualifiers, and your error message specifically says `zsh`. Are you under the mistaken impression you are using `bash`?

Comment: `echo *(N)` produces ``bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('``. I don't know why you think otherwise.

Comment: Have you considered using the `-f` argument to `rm` instead of messing with the glob pattern at all? (BTW, when you self-deleted I was in the middle of flagging for a moderator based on the edit war; using the bash tag for a zsh-only question and refusing to correct it without providing any justification for that unwillingness is Not Okay).

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question

Add `(N)` after the expansion:

```bash
rm *.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,....}(N)
```

Comment: Just to note, `(N)` is treated as literal text by the brace expansion, resulting (as an intermediate step) in `rm *.jpg(N) *.jpeg(N) ...`. Then each pattern has the glob qualifier `N` that sets the `NULL_GLOB` option for that pattern.